# Rasterize shapefile according to another big raster using gdal_rasterize

Tags: raster, shapefile, r, rasterization

I want to rasterize a shapefile into a raster according to another raster (97284, 154208, 15001971072  (nrow, ncol, ncell)).

Since the raster is very big, I am using gdal_rasterize following the code below

```
    rp<-gdal_rasterize(shapefile, big raster)
```

However, I am getting this error

Error in as.character.default() : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

1) What format does the shapefile need to be in to rasterize?
2) Is there another way to rasterize a shapefile? I have tried rasterize() and it is taking very long and I have also read posts that say that gdal_rasterize is much faster for very big raster

Comment: In your code, what are `shapefile` and `big raster`? It would help to include the lines of code that define those variables in your question. gdal_rasterize takes filenames (characters) as arguments. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gdalUtils/versions/2.0.1.14/topics/gdal_rasterize

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment you need to define filename names in character form, and it is usually best to define the bands and the field for rasterization as minimum parameters, e.g.:

```
# write out the blank raster template to 'burn' values into
writeRaster(BigRaster,"./big_raster.tif")
# write out the shapefile
writeOGR(shapefile,".","shape",driver="ESRI Shapefile")

# perform gdal_rasterize, defining band structure (this e.g. b=-1) and field to burn
rg <- gdal_rasterize("shape.shp","big_raster.tif",b=1,a="myfield")
```

this aids speed by not storing all of that raster information in memory and just writing to disk, similar to speed increases found when putting a filename directly inside the `rasterize()` function